# Kue.js worker processing concurrency

Tags: node.js, queueing

I am trying to replace AWS SQS with Kue.js in a node application. 
My concern is, if there are n no of items added in a queue. How many items in the queue will be processed concurrently?

Is it like.... processor will process the each item one at a time or in bulk?

Also if the queue.process() is called for the same queue from two or more different places. how will the processing be done??